# Unexpected end of Stream when calling a controller with parameters, and only on IE11

Tags: asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm experiencing the weirdest issue in my VueJS SPA.

When calling my controller method with axios, which requires a GET parameter, IE11 always ends in a 500-response.

But when calling it the exact same way, with the same code with Chrome or Firefox, there is no issues.

The other weird thing is, when I remove the parameter requirement, and hard code the id, it works fine.

**My controller method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult _method(int id)
{
  var data = methodsThatReturnsData(id);
  return JsonDataResponse(data);
}
```

**The full error from asp.net**

```
IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit!

Apparently, IE11 doesn't like it when you add data options on GET calls.

It adds `content-type` to the header, where the other browsers don't, and ASP.net doesn't like that

**Example:**

```
axios({
  method: options.type,
  url: options.url,
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  },
  data: options.data, <-- Works when removing this for get calls
  params: options.params
})
```